# IONIC : A utility CLI has unexpectedly closed

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-view

I got this error when i run ionic serve
The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.

my ionic info

```
$ionic info
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.0.1 (C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 25.3.1
   NodeJS            : v6.10.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 5.3.0
   OS                : Windows 10

Environment:

   ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Run the below command, being in root directory of Ionic project:

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

Then you can try Ionic serve or Ionic s.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue:

> Assertion `args[1]->IsString()' failed.
>
> A utility CLI has unexpectedly closed

I fixed that by installing natives lib through npm:

```
npm i natives
```

Answer (score 7):

Simpy run

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

and then

```
ionic serve
```

This error is because of some audit during installing a plugin or adding a plug in

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue.  I tried several different solutions, and for some reason different ones worked on different machines. Because I'm an illogical masochist, I attempted to fix this issue in the same project on 3 different laptops instead of sending the new fixed version to the other laptops.

The best answer I came up with is to:

- Delete **node_modules**
- copy **node_modules** from a different project (I used an earlier version of my app)
- run **npm i** to install any missing modules

I think this approach should work for almost all instances.

Answer (score 4):

You must kill the NodeJs service I believe it's a bug

Comment: how can i kill it in windows10? can i close then open vscode again? or you mean stop start services? i run ionic serve in one of my projects. second one working good but first one didnt work as well and this error happened... i dont know why? when copy node_modules from first one to another thats worked fine. but after some days this error returned back to my house

Comment: From the task manager, nodejs must appear to kill. Currently I am not facing this problem maybe it is necessary to update node

Answer (score 3):

Try running:

```
npm install @ionic/lab
```

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing the package.json scripts parts. Worked for me.

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ionic build",
    "serve": "ionic build",
    "start": "npm run serve"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is an issue in your `hosts` file. Make sure your `::1` should enable or not commented.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but using sudo was the only way to solve this on my ubuntu machine!
I just needed to run the command using sudo:

```
sudo ionic serve
```

Answer (score 0):

if you get this in the log:

> The target entry-point "@ionic-native/media-capture" has missing
> dependencies:
>
> - @ionic-native/core

try this,

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/core
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:
[Upgrade Angular](https://update.angular.io/). It'll reveal the real reason for unexpectedly closing in a more verbouse error message. Mine was incompatible dependencies. I simply edited `package.json` with the right depencies, and ran `npm update`

Answer (score 0):

For any Linux Users: This error might occur if you installed node.js via the snapstore. Either change PATH to /usr/local/bin/node or use npm to update/install node.js again at the right place.