# Trying to run “ionic serve”. It shows the errors like this

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, npm, nvm

Trying to run “ionic serve”. It shows the errors like this:
[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 127)

[image]

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51579324/18710595

PS: you're not the first one (and not the last one too) who experience issues like this. I recommand you to check before asking so that you do not create duplicates :)

Edit: Just saw the issue was 4days old, I hope you didn't get blocked too much